# Securing accessing to resource in database by specified id via restful API

Tags: algorithm, api, rest, design-patterns

I have a question about design patterns. Suppose i have restful api and two tables in db:

```
company
---------------
id
Name
Address
```

and

```
User
----------------
Id
Login
Password
CompanyId <-FK to company
```

Let's suppose that user from company 1 is logged in, and want get user data by id, but specified ID has Company Id different than logged in user.

for example:

1) `myapi.com/api/getuser/1 -> user id 1 has the same company as logged in user`

2) `myapi.com/api/getuser/2 -> user id 2 has different company as logged in user (should be unaccessible for logged in user)`

Of course above example is trivial, I asking about more complicated (general) cases, where many tables are in cascade relations.

Do you have any experience with above problem?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: This is a very trivial question indeed. All you need is to write queries. You can use separate queries or can use `join` to write a complex query. BTW, I put it in comment as I'm not clear if you meant something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called tenancy. Principal A is only allowed to view data for other users in Company A. Principal A should not be able to see Company B's user data, and Principal B should not be able to view data for users in Company A. When you have security rules like this that need to be enforced, you are dealing with a multitenant system.

When you have "multiple tables in cascade relations" as you call it, each of those other sets of data should be traceable to a tenancy. You will need to figure out what that tenancy is, and what company / companies the Principal is authorized for. If they don't match, your API should return a 403 Forbidden response.

Comment: Sounds good, first basic idea was encoding ids using for example AES and after request decode in controller and run query. But definitely I would like use some thing according with general design patterns.